# How to import a matplotlib 3D animation in a tkinter frame in python?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, tkinter, 3d

I'm trying to import a matplotlib 3D animation inside a Tkinter window but I got stuck on an error. My Tkinter window has many frames and I try to plot the animation on one of this frame. Finally, I create all elements inside a class init function. So here is a simplified version of my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import  FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.animation as anim
import random

class UI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.back = Frame(master=self.window, width=1200, height=800, bg='white')
        self.rightBack = Frame(master=self.back, width=300, height=800)
        self.rightBack.pack(side='right',padx=2,pady=2)
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.axes = Axes3D(self.fig)

        self.ani = anim.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.updateDisplay, interval=100, blit=False) #  Creating animation

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.displayBack)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH,expand=True)


        # Starting application
        self.window.mainloop()

    def updateDisplay(self,num):
        self.axes.clear()
        self.axes.plot([0,1,random.random()],[0,1,random.random()],[0,1,random.random()],'o',color='k',markersize='5')
```

But when I run the following in python

```
self.ani = anim.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.updateDisplay, interval=100, blit=False)
```

I get this error

```
File "matplotlib/animation.py", line 1703, in __init__
TimedAnimation.__init__(self, fig, **kwargs)

File "matplotlib/animation.py", line 1465, in __init__
event_source = fig.canvas.new_timer()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'new_timer'
```

So I think I understood the error as animation needs a timer but I don't know how to fix it.  Any help? Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation needs to reside in a figure that has a canvas. In your code you define the canvas only *after*  the animation. I suppose it would work as expected if you reverse the order of the animation and the canvas.

```
# First define the canvas
self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, ...)
# only then define the animation
self.ani = anim.FuncAnimation(self.fig, ...)
```

Comment: Yes I did this and it's incredibly working well! Thank you